# What do the functions lowByte() and highByte() do?

Tags: binary, arduino

I've made this small experimental program in Arduino to see how the functions ***lowByte()*** and ***highByte()*** work. What exactly are they supposed to return when passed a value?
    On entering the character '9' in the serial monitor it prints the following:

```
9 
0
218
255
```

How does that come? Also, the last 2 lines are being printed for all values inputted. Why is this happening?

```
int i=12;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop()
{
if(Serial.available())
{
 i = Serial.read() - '0';  // conversion of character to number. eg, '9' becomes 9.
 Serial.print(lowByte(i)); // send the low byte
 Serial.print(highByte(i)); // send the high byte
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

If you have this data:

```
10101011 11001101 // original

// HighByte() get:
10101011

// LowByte() get: 
11001101
```

Answer (score 0):

An `int` is a 16-bit integer on Arduino. So you are reading the high and low part as a byte.

As the actual buffer is `"9\n"`, that is why the second bit prints out 'funny' numbers due to subtracting the result with `'0'`.

Comment: But why am I getting 0? 9 is 1001 in binary. In that case wont the lower byte be 01001?

Comment: The lower byte is `00001001`, they all the same thing!

Comment: Hey I'm just confused here, rookie mistake. I dont really get one thing, why does it print 0 and not `00001001`?

Comment: It prints `9` which is the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

`Serial.print` needs to be formatted to a byte output if that's what you want to see.

Try:

```
Serial.print(lowByte, BYTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rafalenfs' answer, Should you provide a larger data type:

```
00000100 10101011 11001101 // original

// HighByte() will NOT return: 00000100, but will return:
10101011

// LowByte() will still return: 
11001101
```

Highbyte() returns the second lowest bit (as specified by the documentation: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/bits-and-bytes/highbyte/)